# Не запускается связка nginx + php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, php5-fpm

Установил nginx + php5-fpm. 
Конфиг nginx:

```
upstream php-fpm
{
    # PHP5-FPM сервер
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    server_name test.loc;

    root   /home/r/www/test.loc;
    index index.php index.html index.htm; 

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    if ( "$uri" ~ "^/(.*)\/$" ) { return 301 $scheme://$host/$1; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

Такое впечатление, что все завелось, но код php все равно не выполняется. В логи пишется только это:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2016:18:43:32 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
```

Что еще можно сделать, что попробовать? Очень нужен любой совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. убедитесь, что *php-fpm* у вас действительно работает (приведён ориентировочный вывод команды):

   ```
   $ ps aux | grep php-fpm
   root        15  0.0  0.0 205668  9816 ?        Ss   Apr06   0:16 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
   www-data 10154  0.0  0.1 292792 28868 ?        S    12:00   0:03 php-fpm: pool www 
   www-data 20821  0.0  0.1 287408 26336 ?        S    Apr11   0:06 php-fpm: pool www 
   www-data 20917  0.0  0.1 287996 27188 ?        S    Apr11   0:07 php-fpm: pool www
   ```
2. убедитесь, что главный процесс *php-fpm* (*master process*) слушает тот самый unix-сокет, который вы указали в конфигурации (`-p 15` — это *pid* процесса из предыдущего листинга):

   ```
   $ sudo lsof -p 15 | grep sock
   php5-fpm  15 root    6u     unix 0xffff88013784c540      0t0 122854768 socket
   php5-fpm  15 root    8u     unix 0xffff880406709500      0t0 122854769 socket
   php5-fpm  15 root    9u     unix 0xffff880406709c00      0t0 122854770 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
   ```
3. убедитесь, что в указанном вами файле — `fastcgi_params` (находится в конфигурационном каталоге *nginx*, скорее всего, это `/etc/nginx`) — присутствует строка по поводу `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. если присутствует, то, возможно, значение параметра — `$request_filename`, а *php-fpm* ожидает, что там будет `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`.

   у меня (в *debian gnu/linux*), например, в качестве файла с параметрами *fastcgi*, указан не `fastcgi_params`, а `fastcgi.conf`, и вся разница между этими двумя файлами — лишь в наличии во втором этой самой строки

   ```
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   ```

   правда, не могу поручиться, что без неё работать не будет — не проверял.
4. и, конечно, смотрите логи.

Comment: Помог 3й пункт. Не хватало этой строки.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, ваша простая инструкция очень помогла понять принцип настройки. Но в моей установке (Ubuntu 16.04.6 и PHP-FPM 7.3) путь к сокету оказался какой-то нестандартный, я его вычислил как посоветовал aleksandr barakin

И вывод показал путь: /usr/lib/php/20180731/sockets.so

Его я прописал в /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

listen = /usr/lib/php/20180731/sockets.so

И в /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

fastcgi_pass    unix:/usr/lib/php/20180731/sockets.so;

И все заработало! Еще раз благодарю! Возможно мой коммент также кому-то поможет  ;-)