# Комментируется php код на сервере ubuntu+nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm

Почему-то комментируется любой php код на сервере ubuntu+nginx. Но работает phpmyadmin.
Писал примитив

```
phpinfo();
```

nginx conf

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /var/www/site.ru;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name site.ru;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}

#error_page 404 /404.html;


location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}


}
```

Comment: А расширение файла точно php?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не запускается связка nginx + php5-fpm](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512399/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-nginx-php5-fpm)

Comment: точно, он его переделывает в комментарий html <!--phpinfo();-->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле php.ini поменять short_open_tag на On