# nginx к php не подключается что не так?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, http, debian

Взял vps сервер, развернута там debine 8. Воткнул туда nginx 1.10.1, установил php. Все работает, кроме php. Вот конфиг nginx, что я не правильно сделал?

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root   html;
        index index.php;
       location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/phpfpm-webpanels.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    include fastcgi_params;
}
location ~ ^/(fpmstat|ping)$ {
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ***.***.***.***;
    deny all;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /fpmstat;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/phpfpm-webpanels.sock;
}

location ~* ^.+.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt)$ {
    expires 60d;
}
          location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }  
         location /stat.xsl {
            root html;
        }
        location /hls {  
           #server hls fragments  
            types{  
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;  
                video/mp2t ts;  
            }  
            alias temp/hls;  
            expires -1;  
        } 
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }  
}
```

В логах не мог найти sock нужный, я исправил и ошибки перестали выходить, но php по прежнему не работает.
Вот код нового config

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  myname;
        root   html;
        index index.php;
         location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
 }
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 }

          location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }  
         location /stat.xsl {
            root html;
        }
        location /hls {  
           #server hls fragments  
            types{  
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;  
                video/mp2t ts;  
            }  
            alias temp/hls;  
            expires -1;  
        } 
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: проверяли, что `php-fpm` запущен? что он создает сокет `/var/run/phpfpm-webpanels.sock`? Логи смотрели?

Comment: @approximatenumber по вашему совету посмотрел, теперь нужный сокет есть, но php по прежнему не работает, можете увидеть новый конфиг выше... Подскажите что я делаю не так,

Comment: а логи самого php-fpm смотрели? и его конфиг тоже надо правильно настроить.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/512496/178576